# Couldn't match expected type 'Integer -> t' with actual type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to run this textbook example but I keep getting this error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Integer -> t'
              with actual type `[Char]'
* The function `showPerson' is applied to two arguments,
  but its type `People -> [Char]' has only one
  In the expression: showPerson "charles" 18
  In an equation for `it': it = showPerson "charles" 18
* Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:38:1)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I'm inputting the correct types. 
My code is:

```
type Name = String 
type Age = Int
data People = Person Name Age

showPerson :: People -> String
showPerson (Person a b) = a ++ " -- " ++ show b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `showPerson` function, as declared, has only one argument. This argument is of type `People`.

However, judging by the error you're quoting, you are trying to call this function with two arguments - `"charles"` and `18`. The first argument is of type `String`, second - of type `Int`.

This is what the compiler is trying to tell you when it says:

```
The function `showPerson' is applied to two arguments, 
but its type `People -> [Char]' has only one
```

To correctly call your function, you need to first create a value of type `People`, then pass that value to the function as argument:

```
p = Person "charles" 18
showPerson p
```

Or the same thing in one line:

```
showPerson (Person "charles" 18)
```

Comment: Understand now! Thanks!